# How to pull future SQL tables into PowerBI automatically?

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am new to both PowerBI and SQL databases (and databases in general), so please forgive me if I'm not using correct verbiage or if this is something answered else where. Being new to both limits my Googling knowledge to find the correct answer (if it's out there.)

I have a SQL database that automatically creates new tables for data every month. I have a PowerBI project that I'm trying to query those tables and pull form the correct months. All of my SQL tables that I'm interested in pulling are called:

dbo.sqlt_1_202x_yy where x represents the year and yy represents the month.

examples: dbo.sqlt_1_2023_07 and dbo.sqlt_1_2022_11

I don't want to come into PowerBI each month and add a new table (ie next month add dbo.sqlt_1_2023_08) to the project.

I tried using   `Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="sqlt_data_1_*"]}[Data],` to see if that would work, but it doesn't appear to have worked.

Is there a way to make it so these automatically get into PowerBI?

Edit: adding a picture of the SQL database structure for clarity.

[image: This is an Image of the DB Hierarchy for Clarity]

Comment: Although you can probably do this in Power BI, creating a table per month is not ani idela design. A better design is to have one table which has an additional column for the month. If you are new to data, what I recommend is you try both designs so you can practically understand the pros and cons of each approach. Also just a general comment, the sentence _doesn't appear to have worked_ has no practical information about what the problem is. Good luck in your data journey! It's an exciting time right now.

Comment: One way to do this is to create a stored procedure in SQL Server, and inside the stored procedure, create a temporary table to store the contents of the tables. Then you could query the sys.all_objects table for the tables matching your criteria. Then you'd use a cursor to loop over all those and insert the contents of each table into your temp table. Then return that in your TVF/stored procedure.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when i do data in Excel, I do my best to avoid adding columns for various reasons. Out of curiosity why would increasing columns for the months make more sense than just having them create a new table? Further, the unfortunate thing is the table is made directly from the software that I use and I don't get to decide how it works outside of what reset period to use, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly, etc. I chose monthly to keep tables smaller for queries. (just giving insight into my choices, not that they're right etc). Thanks for advice!

Comment: @Pieter sadly, I do not understand the slightest bit of what you mention here. I will ask ChatGPT to try to make sense of it for me lol. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear the solution is not to continuously add columns, it is to have one file (or table) with one column which contains the month number. Then you just import that into Power BI and you can use a slicer on the month column. Having said that it's quite typical for data to arrive in the format you mention. It's _not_ typical for a database system to create a table per period though, that's a pretty bad red flag.

Comment: Oh I just realised these are tables not files. Yes it is a very bad red flag that the system is doing it this way. It's a terrible design. Anyway this is the general way that this can be done. You'll need to experiment a bit and you might want to do an introductory course on M (the language Power BI uses to import data) https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Combine-multiple-tables-using-dynamic-list/td-p/1794552

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you for the course recommendation! I will work on that as I go!  Interesting that it's a red flag. I would've expected it to be a relatively normal way of doing data. In my head at least. But I guess maybe it's similar to creating a new Excel workbook for every month of data. That infuriates me.  So maybe it's the same? I added a picture of what I'm working with if that helps in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the M code the GUI builds: (copy & Paste and fix... LOL)

```
let
    Source = Sql.Databases("DESKTOP-FPIQ4KB"),
    Scratch = Source{[Name="Scratch"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Scratch, each Text.StartsWith([Item], "sqlt_")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each ([Schema] = "SchemaTwo")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Name", "Schema", "Kind"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", {"PersonID", "BirthDate"}, {"Data.PersonID", "Data.BirthDate"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

In my case, all my tables are in SchemaTwo, and then all the tables have the same prefix. And the tablename starts with "tsqlt_". (Yours could be longer). That's a query, so every time you connect, PowerQuery will query your database to grab only the tables matching those criteria. Then you can append them all as a new table.

The end result will be one table with all the records from the various tables that start with "tsqlt_"

Expanding the data etc basically does an append so all your records from the database that match the various search criteria are brought into PowerBI. The M code is basically a query (describes what data to go get), so you just run it and it will bring in refreshed data.

Comment: This looks close also. Right now I'm trying to take what you have and plug my stuff in. And it's not liking me sadly lol. I tried the following and was going to expand after.  This gave me an "Expression.Error: the key didn't match any rows in the table.  ` let
    Source = Sql.Database("MyDB"),
    Scratch = Source{[Name="Tables"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Scratch, each Text.StartsWith([Item], "sqlt_")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each ([Schema] = "dbo"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"` and apparently i can't figure out the mini-Markdown:(

Comment: I love you. i was stuck at the Scratch=Source part but I guess you can skip navigation by clicking on the db name. ` let
    Source = Sql.Database("MyDB"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Item], "sqlt_")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each ([Schema] = "dbo")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Name", "Schema", "Kind"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", {"my columns"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"`

Comment: I received an error at your exapanded columns bc i obvi dont have the same data. But i was able to click on the "expanded data" applied step and select my columns instead. Thanks!

Comment: Did it work? (Yeah, that part of PowerQuery is CONFUSING!), but once you get it working, you're all set!

Comment: Now i have a new problem though. the cumulative data has 5 million rows and takes a hot minute to update. Would there be a way so that it only queries the data that I'm looking for? Lets say I want to query from 5/3/2023 to today, in Excel I would use parameters to only query that range. Can I do the same in PowerBI? Generally, w this data I will probably only ever need the most recent 2-3 months maybe.  Thoughts? TIA

Comment: i would upvote the answer but i only have 11 rep lol.

Comment: Wait, since the data is coming from SQL Server... you can write a query/stored procedure there to limit the data so you only get N days or months of data. That's the best place to filter (if you can). Otherwise, you'd do that in PowerQuery. Did you mean you wanted to pass a parameter value (like "Choose a start date")?

Comment: I think I want to choose a start/end date... I'm not sure though. But maybe just filtering the last 90 days would be a start.  I doubt there will ever need to be a reason for me to choose anything outside of the last 90 days. But you never know. So I like to be prepared lol.

Comment: This is one of the things that has always driven me nuts about PowerBI. I have to test it, but maybe you can use Parameters to pass the max # of days to a stored procedure.

Comment: gotcha. the fun part is my date is a timestamp and isnt a date. so thanks to you and chatGPT i was able to get it to do the last 30 days. HOWEVER. its at the end of my applied steps. and it still takes 5 minutes for it to load :(. so I will probably need to figure out your query/stored procedure to work properly. This is suggesting we move to chat. I dont know how to do that sadly. but i definitely appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you have a date column in the table you can use as a date? Then you can create a view or stored procedure that does something like
WHERE Mytable.TheDate >= GETDATE()-30; If you do that, make sure you index the date column.

Comment: in those tables, i only have a T_stamp. ChatGPT has me do the following conversion in PowerQuery to get the date/time from the table for sorting purposes #"Converted to Date/Time" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Data", "DateTime", each #datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + #duration(0, 0, 0, [Data.t_stamp] / 1000)),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Date/Time", {{"DateTime", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

Answer (score 0):

I just [found this](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Dynamically-change-data-source-from-SQL-database/m-p/405285) which looks like it might help.
Essentially create a new table that has the specific naming convention that you're looking for, then amend the source to look for the most recent.
Not sure if you need to also maintain the previous records within the dashboard, but hopefully will give a head start.

Comment: I think this is a good start. I will have to see how to relate it back to what I'm doing... I guess I don't understand how if I'm pulling data from a PowerBI dashboard, how I would interact with it so that it knows where to pull from...? if that makes sense...

Comment: I think you have it upside down. [Data Import]=>[Transformation]=>[Data Model]=>[Dashboard]. The dashboard is the top level object. You'd specify the database you're connecting to, and then you'd filter that down to just the tables you want, and then to the columns you want. Then you relate tables...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).